# AWS Fargate task has no exit code

Tags: aws-fargate

When I run a Fargate task, 99% of the time it shows an exit code and has logs in CloudWatch. For example:

[image: Fargate task with exit code]

However, every now and again it shows no exit code and has no logs in CloudWatch. It appears as though the task was never run and provides no explanation for why it was not run. Example:

[image]

Is this normal to not have logs or an exit code? Is there anyway I can find out about why this task was not run?

Comment: Anything in the Events for the service?

Comment: @bluescores what is the Events? Is this something in CloudWatch?

Comment: From the ECS console home, Click Clusters on the left-nav; then Cluster name > Service name > Events tab

Comment: @bluescores I didn't try that yet. I'll have to reproduce this error and give that a check!